# Tailwind not watching parent folder even though specified

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a content configuration in tailwind to watch php files that are up a directory from where the `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    jit: true,
    purge: {
        content: ["./templates/**/*.{html,php}", "./assets/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "../*.{php}"]
    },
    

...
```

The files that are in `../*.{php}` are not being transformed or watch by tailwind. When i build, these css styles and class names that are in this folder are not being built.

Is it not possible to watch a parent directory with tailwind?

Comment: I think it is possible. Try an exact file to see if that works first `"../index.php"` or also `"../**/*.{php}"`

Comment: With Tailwind v3.1.2 I am successfully using `content: ["./**/*.php", ]` if that helps.

Comment: @stickyuser how is that up a folder?

Comment: Oh, because that second comment is from my `tailwind.config.js` file which is actually in a folder called `css`. But the `content` setting is relative to the root of the project, i.e. up one folder. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think it would help if you published your folder directory, because I am having a hard time imagining it.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have this working for a WordPress theme using Tailwind.

Top level folder has `package.json`, and files like `header.php`, `footer.php` and `index.php`.

`package.json` includes the build scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "postcss css/tailwind.css --output tailwind.css --watch",
    "build": "postcss css/tailwind.css --output tailwind.css"
  },
```

In a folder `/css` I have the following:

`postcss.config.js`, note it has the config setting:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    "tailwindcss/nesting": {},
    tailwindcss: { config: './css/tailwind.config.js' },
    autoprefixer: {},
    cssnano: {
      preset: "default",
      autoprefixer: { add: false },
    },
  },
}
```

`tailwind.config.js` includes the content setting:

```
content: ["./**/*.php", ]
```

`tailwind.css` is also there with the usual:

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

Then from the top level directory I can run `npm run dev`.

Hopefully that can help you get it working with you desired setup.